# Running both iron-router and collection-api at the same time

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to run iron-router and collection-api at the same time but it seems like iron-router take the request and do nothing.

When I'm start meteor is says that collection-api is running

```
$ meteor
=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/
I20140214-08:26:16.584(1)? Collection API v0.1.15 running at /collectionapi
```

but when I'm trying to send data to the api the request times out.

```
curl -d "{mydata: \"data\"}" http://localhost:3000/collectionapi
```

My main.js with the iron-router config looks like this:

```
$ cat client/main.js
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'siteLayout'
});
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'home',
  })
  this.route('organic');
  this.route('scales');
  this.route('tags');
});
```

Do someone knows how to configure the iron-router to play nice with the collection-api?

Comment: I think you need to give more details – "take the request"?

Comment: A workaround I found was to configure collection-api to run in standalone mode on a other port.

`new CollectionAPI({standAlone: true, listenPort: 3005});`